# vec!() dereferencing when iterating with explicit type

Tags: rust

```
  let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  let even_numbers: Vec<i32> = numbers.iter().filter(|&n| n % 2 == 0).map(|n| *n).collect();
    
  let even_numbers: Vec<_> = numbers.iter().filter(|&n| n % 2 == 0).map(|n| n).collect();
```

When the type is explicit I have to dereference `n` but if I don't state the type the compiler seems to know and automatically picks the value. Am I missing something, should it not be the other way around?

Why do I have to dereference with the explicit type but don't need to with `_`?

Comment: *"the compiler knows and automatically picks the value"* - which is different than the one you picked in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.iter()` produces an iterator with an element type of `&i32`.

To collect into a `Vec<i32>`, you have to reference to copy the actual integer from the reference. That's what `.map(|n| *n)` does. (BTW `.copied()` exists for this purpose).

The `Vec<_>` tells the compiler "I just want a vector, but *infer* the element type" so it does just that and picks the element type from the iterator: `&i32`.

You can instead use `.into_iter()` on the original `Vec`, which will consume the vector and return an iterator of owned (not references) elements (`i32`) directly.